# How to git stage changes in JetBrains IDE or similar functionality

Tags: git, jetbrains-ide, rider

How to add files to git stage in JetBrains Rider? Is this feature implemented? If it's not implemented then in which window can I look through the staged files which I've staged using some external tool?

[UPD]:
The use case is to hold separately files I want to commit and files I don't want to commit at the particular moment. Stash is not the solution because I need all changes to be present. VS has this functionality and it's very convenient. You can stage and unstage any files with a single right mouse button click.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The **staging area** is an alternative to **changelists** that *@Jura Gorohovsky* has mentioned. For those more comfortable with the concept of staging changes on a file-by-file basis like the Visual Studio experience you described, you basically need to do two things:

#### 1. Enable Staging Area

1. Open the Rider IDE settings (**File > Settings...** or `Ctrl+Alt+S`)
2. Search for "stage",
3. Click to **[x] Enable staging area**

[image]

#### 2. Open the Commit Window and Stage Your Files

1. Open the **Commit** window (**View > Tool Windows > Commit**)
2. On your desired file **Right-click > Stage** (or individually **Unstage**)
3. As you enter a commit message and click **Commit**, it will commit only the files you've staged

There's a ton of other more complex maneuvers (see Reference) but that's the basics.

[image]

Reference: [Official Docs for staging area to commit changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Commit_and_push_changes.html#use-git-staging-area-to-commit-changes)

Answer (score 16):

To separate files that you want to commit/push later, you can use **changelists**.

1. Select *View | Tool Windows | Version Control* (or press `Alt+9`) to open the *Version Control* tool window.
2. In the *Local Changes* tab of the tool window, select one or multiple items.
3. Right-click and select *Move to Another Changelist...*, or press `Alt+Shift+M`, to move selected items to an existing or a new changelist. Select *Set active* if you want all new modifications to be auto-added to the new/target checklist.

The above is applicable to Rider and all other IntelliJ Platform-based IDEs (IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm, PyCharm, PhpStorm etc.), as well as to all version control systems that they support (Git, Mercurial, Subversion, Perforce out of the box; other VCS via plugins).

[image: Move to Another Changelist command in JetBrains Rider]

Source: [Official Rider docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Managing_Changelists.html)

Comment: Is there a way to unstage them back?

Comment: @JerrySmith You mean undo an accidental stage? *Revert* should work (*VCS | Git | Revert*, `Ctrl+Alt+Z`).

Comment: BTW if there's a Git command that you're looking for but it's not available or isn't immediately discoverable in Rider's version control UI, there's always an option to use the *Terminal* tool window (*View | Tool Windows | Terminal*, usually `Alt+F12`) to execute any Git command.

Comment: no, I mean preserve changes but to move selected files from index to the unstaged area

Comment: @JerrySmith I don't think there's a UI command for this. Can you elaborate why you want to do this?

Comment: The use case is to hold separately files I want to commit and files I don't want to commit at the particular moment. Stash is not the solution because I need all changes to be present. VS has this functionality and it's very convenient. You can stage and unstage any files with a single right mouse button click.

Comment: @JerrySmith Ah, you need [changelists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Managing_Changelists.html) then. Right-click a file in *Local Changes*, and select *Move to Another Changelist...* (`Alt+Shift+M`).

Comment: @JerrySmith You might want to add the use case to the question, and I will then update my answer. This will hopefully make the Q/A more searchable and useful for other visitors.

Comment: Wow, changelists work like magic! And actually they are better because you can have as many of them as you want. Please, update your answer and I'll mark you as accepted.

Comment: @JerrySmith Perfect! Updated the answer.

Comment: I've found recently that changelists allow you to move parts of the same file from one changelist to another. Right click on the file in the changelist --> show diff --> right click to the particular change --> move to another changelist. That makes changelist the complete replacement for git stage.